# Changing first child div in directive

Tags: angularjs

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/n90Je6zooXneXSobsSfX?p=preview) I have a directive that's a div with orange border. I'm trying to (unsuccessfully) change the border color in the link function. The two lines change the directive div to green and red(try uncommenting each), not the first child (element[0]). How to make this work?

Javascript:

```
angular.module('app')
    .directive('dir1', function() {


    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'E';

    directive.template = '<div style="width:200px;height:200px;border:2px solid orange">' + 
'<div style="width:100px;height:100px;border:2px solid black"></div></div>';

    directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {

      angular.element(element[0]).css('border','2px solid red');
      //element.css('border','2px solid green');

    };

    return directive;

});
```

**UPDATE:**

added an inner div, its color shouldn't change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your div with `element.find`. Try this:

```
element.find('div').eq(0).css('border', '2px solid blue')
```

Comment: why can't I just access the div with element[0] directly?

Comment: because element[0] is `<dir1>`. you can set `directive.replace = true` and then use element[0]

Comment: if element[0] is <dir1>, then what's element ?

Comment: "element is the jqLite-wrapped element that this directive matches"

Comment: when to use element[0] and when to use element?

Comment: use element[0] when you want to access the actual DOM node. use element when you want to manipulate or retrieve value, with functions like: css, find, eq, attr, etc.. element.find('div').css for example will change all the divs inside that element wrapper